# how to define name space to deploy except default namespace when using kubernetes continuous deploy plugin

Tags: jenkins, slave

I haven't any clue for how to give the specific namespace where I want to deploy my app kubernetesDeploy(kubeconfigId: 'test', configs: "test.yml")

I am slave in one cluster and need to deploy in another cluster. The deployment always goes to the default namespace

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8cpZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set namespace as parametric to take parameter from pipeline;

yml;

```
namespace: ${PIPELINE_NAMESPACE}
```

---

Pipeline;

```
env.PIPELINE_NAMESPACE = "test"
kubernetesDeploy(kubeconfigId: 'test', configs: "test.yml")
```